# jQuery autocomplete for dynamic multiple records

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-autocomplete

I have the following HTML:

```
<input name="data[Content][0][name]" type="text" class="content_name_1" id="content_name" >


<input name="data[Content][1][name]" type="text" class="content_name_2" id="content_name" >
                             ........


<input name="data[Content][n][name]" type="text" class="content_name_n" id="content_name" >
```

And the following jQuery-Code:

```
$('input[name="data[Content][0][name]"]').autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: function(request, response){
            $.ajax({
                url: '/contents/ajax_search/' + request.term,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

I create dynamicly HTML input fields and I want to link them with the autocomplete function, but i just can do this with one of them. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: put jquery inside the loop where u create textbox dynamically and pass the textbox name to jquery ,jquery created for individual

Answer (score 1):

First method is to use multiple selectors,

```
$('input[name="data[Content][0][name]"], input[name="data[Content][1][name], input[name="data[Content][2][name]"]"] ').autocomplete({
    });
```

Second method is to add `class="common"` in all your html boxes and use the class name as selector

```
$('.common').autocomplete({
    });
```

Comment: I already tried these two methods but they both dont´t work. With the first method only the first input works with the autocomplete. The other don´t work.

Comment: i just noticed you have the same id on all 3, thats probably the reason why

Comment: It works now! I put jQuery in the loop where I create the inputs

Comment: Yes, I had to do the same thing to make it work with the dynamically injected textboxes.